# Send-MailMessage with csv as attachment in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to send an email with a `.csv` file as attachment. I export it as CSV but once PS tries to attach it this is what displays

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Attachments'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a 
>   collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Here's the code that I have

```
$TableCont = @() # HASH TABLE TO SORT INFORMATION 
foreach ($item in $Events) { 
    $tabledata = [ordered]@{
        action                      = $item.action
        clientASNDescription        = $item.clientASNDescription
        datetime                    = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime([datetime]$item.datetime, $pdtz) 
    }
    $TableCont += New-Object psobject -Property $tabledata
}

$TableCont | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\Scripts\test.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -Force
$raw_data = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\test.csv'
```

And this is what `test.csv` contains

```
action      clientASNDescription     datetime
------      --------------------     ---------------------
challenge                            5/27/2020  1:16:18 PM
challenge   8102                     5/27/2020  1:16:18 PM
challenge                            5/27/2020  1:16:18 PM
```

As you may notice there are some null or blank values in the `.csv` file, that's what the error says, that null values are some kind of blocking the email to be sent. Do you have any idea how can I avoid it?

This is the code that sends the email

```
Send-MailMessage -To bryan@example.com `
        -Body "$body" -BodyAsHtml `
        -SmtpServer smtp.test.net `
        -Subject "TEST " `
        -Attachments "$raw_data" `
        -from example@example.com. `
        -priority High `
        -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-Attachments` parameter requires path to the file that needs to be attached.

So your code should be `-Attachments @('C:\Scripts\test.csv')` instead of the csv contents.

From documentation:

> Specifies the path and file names of files to be attached to the email
>   message. You can use this parameter or pipe the paths and file names
>   to Send-MailMessage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1#parameters

Comment: Now it says that `Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Attachments'. Specified method is not supported.
`

Comment: Try without the `@()` symbols. e.g. `-Attachements 'C:\Scripts\test.csv' `.

Comment: No, I'm still getting the same error as the original question, the `null` values in the `.csv`

Comment: So, I didn't figure it out, I just run it from the server and it shows no errors now, it sends the email with the attachment. I think it is solved now but I don't know how.